# Create sudoers config allow user to run ifconfig etc commands only

Tags: networking, ifconfig, sudoers

I've trying to modify the sudoers file so a user can only run commands such as ifconfig etc.
I've found though the user I created can already run commands and aren't sure how to limit them.

```
# User priviledge specification
test ALL=/sbin/ifconfig
```

And that saves ok without a syntax error. Does anyone know how I could make this the only command user test can execute?

Answer (score 0):

In most Linux distributions you are able to run the program /sbin/ifconfig without root privileges. No sudoers setup required here. For privileged operations (changing network settings, bringing interfaces up/down, ...) the tool checks the privileges on itself.

I am assuming you want the user test to be able to change network settings which makes it necessary to configure sudo.

I am not 100% sure whether your sudoers syntax is correct. Try this:

```
test ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /sbin/ifconfig
```